Android - Java - BroadcastReceiver.onReceive() is not called after sent SMS
My Xiaomi doesn't send SMS at all, but the SMS is listed as unsent in the message history of the default SMS client.
Samsung will real send the SMS, but BroadcastReceiver.onReceive() is not called and my app don't know if it was sent. Result of sms.sent() is my timeout error message.
(I'm not a Java developer - I just put together all the solutions I found. If you see any mistakes, please do not hesitate to point them out to me.)
LogCat show:

I SmsServiceModule: onReceiveSmsMessage: errorCode=-1

SMS.java:
public class SMS {
    public Context context = null;

    SMS(Context context) { this.context = context; }

    static class Result {
        public String status = null;
        public String body = null;
        public String error = null;

        Result(String body) { this.body = body; }
        Result(String body, String error) { this.error = error; }
        Result(String body, String error, String status) {
            if (body != null && !body.equals(""))
                 this.body = body;
            else this.error = error;
            this.status = status;
        }
    }

    public static String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    public static String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    public Result sendSMS(JSONObject input) {
        final Result[] res = {null};

        try {
            ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPendingIntents      = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
            ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveredPendingIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            ArrayList<String> mSMSMessage = smsManager.divideMessage(input.getString("message"));

            for (int i = 0; i < mSMSMessage.size(); i++) {
                Intent iSent = new Intent(SENT)
                    .setPackage(context.getPackageName())
                    .setClass(context, SMSBroadcastReceiver.class)
                    .putExtra("result", res);
                Intent iDelivered = new Intent(DELIVERED)
                    .setPackage(context.getPackageName())
                    .setClass(context, SMSBroadcastReceiver.class)
                    .putExtra("result", res);

                PendingIntent sentPI      = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, iSent,      PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
                PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, iDelivered, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

                sentPendingIntents.add(i, sentPI);
                deliveredPendingIntents.add(i, deliveredPI);
            }

            BroadcastReceiver sentReceiver = new SMSBroadcastReceiver();
            context.registerReceiver(sentReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT), context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED);

            BroadcastReceiver deliveredReceiver = new SMSBroadcastReceiver();
            context.registerReceiver(deliveredReceiver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED), context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED);

            smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(input.getString("number"), null, mSMSMessage, sentPendingIntents, deliveredPendingIntents);

            int miliSecSleep = 300;
            int miliSecMax = 1000 * 18;
            int miliSecDeliveredMin = 1000 * 5;
            while (miliSecMax > 0) {
                Thread.sleep(miliSecSleep);
                miliSecMax = miliSecMax - miliSecSleep;
                miliSecDeliveredMin = miliSecDeliveredMin - miliSecSleep;

                if (res[0] != null && (res[0].status.equals(DELIVERED) || miliSecDeliveredMin < 0)) {
                    if (res[0].error != null)
                         Log.e("~=", res[0].error);
                    else Log.d("~=", res[0].body);

                    break;
                }
            }
            if (res[0] == null) {
                res[0] = new Result("", "SMS status: 25s TimeOut for SMS sending has expired");
            }

            context.unregisterReceiver(sentReceiver);
            context.unregisterReceiver(deliveredReceiver);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("~=", "SMS error: " + e.toString());
            res[0] = new Result("", "SMS error: " + e.toString());
        }

        return res[0];
    }

}

service.java:
public class SMSService extends Service {
    SMS sms = new SMS(this);

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        sms.sent('123456', 'test message');

SMSBroadcastReceiver.java:
public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("~=", "this is never be called");

        Functions.Result[] result = intent.getExtras().getParcelableArray("result", Functions.Result.class);

        SmsMessage smsM = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(
            intent.getByteArrayExtra("pdu"),
            intent.getStringExtra("format")
        );

        if (getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK || (smsM != null && smsM.getStatus() == Telephony.Sms.STATUS_COMPLETE))
            result[0] = new Functions.Result(intent.getAction() + " status: DONE", null, intent.getAction());
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(Functions.SENT))
            result[0] = new Functions.Result(null, intent.getAction() + " status: " + getConstantName(getResultCode(), SmsManager.class), intent.getAction());
        else if (smsM != null && smsM.getStatus() == Telephony.Sms.STATUS_FAILED)
            result[0] = new Functions.Result(null, intent.getAction() + " status: STATUS_FAILED (SMS not delivered)", intent.getAction());
    }

    private String getConstantName(int value, Class<?> cls) {
        for ( java.lang.reflect.Field f : cls.getDeclaredFields()) {
            int mod = f.getModifiers();
            if (Modifier.isStatic(mod) && Modifier.isPublic(mod) && Modifier.isFinal(mod)) {
                try {
                    // Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format("%s = %d%n", f.getName(), (int) f.get(null)));
                    if ((int) f.get(null) == value) return f.getName();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}

MainActivity.java -> permissions for: READ_SMS, SEND_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS
AndroidManifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Material3.DayNight"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".SMSService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".SMSBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483645">
                <action android:name="SMS_SENT" />
                <action android:name="SMS_DELIVERED" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>


"I just put together all the solutions I found." – There's a lot of stuff out there that's too simplistic for actual use, and/or just flat out wrong, and it's nigh impossible to tell what's what at first glance. Also, there are several moving parts involved in this kind of functionality, and cramming it into one method is going to be shaky at best. If you wanna have a look, I've a complete example that I put together to update a previous post: https://github.com/gonodono/sms-sender. The architecture may not be perfect, but the SMS stuff is all correct, AFAIK. It works on my Samsungs, btw.

Oops, I kinda forgot, it's in Kotlin. It's not too different than Java, though.

Hi @MikeM.. I went through your app and will try to modify my code accordingly. Unfortunately, my problem was not solved. Can you please see what I'm doing wrong?

Here ya go: https://gist.github.com/gonodono/8802779b2119497b848b72803fbaeec1. Ignore the overall name; I forgot that Gists are named after the first file, and I'm too lazy to change it. I stripped out most everything that wasn't necessary for this particular functionality, but I tried to keep your identifiers where possible, so that you can copy/paste it without too much trouble, hopefully. It's tested and working, and I ran a couple with my fake delivery report thingy to make sure that works, too. Lemme know if you have any issues with the code; I haven't done Java in a while.

Big thanks @MikeM. I was already completely depressed. I combined your (in my opinion non-essential parts of) the code with my code, and inexplicably it started working for me on the Samsung \o/. It either doesn't work on Xiaomi, or it works completely randomly, and the delivered event message can't be recognized at all (SmsMessage.createFromPdu() is null), but for now I probably don't have the nerve for next edit of my solution. After this SMS experience, I consider Android to be a very bad OS. I'm glad that I'm not officially developing mobile apps :D .
Just for fun, the current version of my code is here https://github.com/ObscurusGrassator/jjplugin-sms/tree/main/android-apk-source/app/src/main/java/jjplugin/obsgrass/sms
Java @MikeM solution: https://gist.github.com/gonodono/8802779b2119497b848b72803fbaeec1
Kotlin @MikeM solution: https://github.com/gonodono/sms-sender
